# Informatica Parameter File Management

Tags: parameter-passing, session-variables, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We're planning to create a Parameter File in Informatica PowerCenter that has some static and dynamic values. Our global values will be static and session parameters will be dynamic.

Our parameter file looks like:

```
[GLOBAL]
$$SchemaName_1=S1
$$SchemaName_2=S2

[session_1]
$$LastDate=2020-01-01

[session_2]
$$LastDate=2021-06-01
```

The question is, how can we update the session specific parameter values in parameter file but keep the others so we can use the file in other workflows. We need to update the values from the workflow, not directly updating the file.

Comment: Only way is to do it is to use shell script. Or some mapping which generates this kind of param file. Better idea may be to use multiple files one file for one workflow - easy to manage/generate.

Comment: If you can compute or extract from the database the session parameter values, you could use a mapping to write these values to a file, then a command to append global values and session values in the same file, and finally use that file as the session parameter file for the last two sessions. Saves you from using Shell, but makes it harder to understand, see what's better for you !